# Sort paragraphs in a text file alphabetically using Python

Tags: python, sorting, text-files, paragraph

I need to sort paragraphs alphabetically according to a filename used in each paragraph. Here is an example how it looks like (there is around 200 paragraphs like these in a text file):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
L:hwqw\se\hf8594.txt

File Creation Date:            September 07, 2004
Identifier #:                  hf8594.tif
Image Pixels (meters):         1.25
Format:                        8 bit TIFF

------------------------------------------------------------------
L:hhtk\ha8421.txt

File Creation Date:            September 07, 2004
Identifier #:                  ha8421.tif
Image Pixels (meters):         1.25
Format:                        8 bit TIFF
```

Now I need to sort the paragraphs according to the `Identifier #` (identifier has the same name as the text file on the top, but the text files are in different subfolders, so I think it would be better to use the identifier).

Comment: well I don't know how to even start, because I am beginner in Python

Comment: Yeah, nothing wrong with a beginner question in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Split the paragraphs string to get each paragraph in a list.

This can be achieved using

```
paragraph_sep = "------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
paragraphs = paragraph_str.split(paragraph_sep)[1:]
```

## Extract the identifier from each paragraph item.

This can be done using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

```
import re
s = 'Identifier #:                  hf8594.tif'
comp = re.compile("Identifier #: \s* (.*tif)")
a = re.search(comp, s)
a.groups()
=> ('hf8594.tif',)
```

## Sort the paragraphs list with the identifier.

Note that you can easily pass a function to set the keys to the sorting function.

```
comp = re.compile("Identifier #: \s* (.*tif)")
def get_id_from_string(s):
    ids = re.search(comp, s)
    return ids[0]
paragraphs.sort(key=get_id_from_string)
```

## Reconstruct the string

With `sep.join(paragraphs)`

You now have the different steps, hope it help.